# Merg two list to get Third List both Lists Have two common and one different Column c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, merge

I have two lists,

```
List <AgencyCount> Agency= AgencyList.ToList();
List<IndCount> Ind = individualList.ToList();
```

want to merge it into third list that is,

```
List<complain> list = new List<complain>();
```

Columns in  Agency list,

```
CityId
CityNM
Acount
```

Columns in  Ind list,

```
CityId
CityNM
Icount
```

Third list is using object of class type that is

```
CityId
CityNM
Acount
Icount
```

Values in the Agency and Ind list for the first two columns are same.

Resulting List get values for the first two column that is same and than get third column of both list as showns above.

Comment: I see nothing in these queries that can't be done with LINQ to Entities. Any reason you're using direct SQL?

Comment: because I am unable to use Linq to Entities for this scenario :(

Comment: specially left join part

Comment: You mean *you don't know how* to do left join in LINQ. Left join is done with `DefaultIfEmpty()`. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins) for more info.

Comment: @Tsahi I used liq to ef but not getting appropriate result so using this can you please tell me how to merge two list into third one i will update this post so you can see

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. As you said, that  AgencyList and IndividualList has CityId and city_NM as common values, I'm assuming that the join of both lists are with these fields
The linq query returns an anonymous type, that you compose with fields from both lists. You can return a concrete object simply creating a new `ResultClass` and doing `select new ReturnClass {` in the linq

*Updated as per @tsahi Asher comment*

```
var qry = from a in AgencyList.ToList()
          join i in individualList.ToList() 
          on a.CityId equals i.City_NM
          select new {
              a.yourField,
              i.otherField
          };
return qry.ToList();
```

Comment: You may have to materialize the lists (call `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` on them) before querying them. `.SqlQuery<T>()` returns `DbRawSqlQuery<TResult>`, which is an `IQueryable<T>` that doesn't include actual results before it is iterated.

Comment: There is no reason to do `ToList` on the two source database tables.

Answer (score 0):

@mnieto's answer was correct for the original question, which was completely rewritten (please don't do that, it leads to answers to non-existent questions like this). For the current version of the question, the answer is very similar, with only a different `join` condition:

```
var qry = from a in Agency
          join i in Ind
          on new { a.CityId, a.CityNM } equals new { i.CityId, i.CityNM }
          select new {
              a.CityId,
              a.CityNM,
              a.Acount,
              i.Icount
          };
return qry.ToList();
```

Comment: `&&` is invalid in a query syntax `join` statement.

Comment: @NetMage right. I fixed it. please upvote back, thanks.